# Refresh inside function of react-navigation screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using **react-navigation** I am doing stuff inside one of screens, where I display items, and optionally delete them. When deleting, I need to update the screen, which I am having trouble with. I tried navigating to the same screen or updating useState hook variables, which should re-render the screen but dont. For now, I am refreshing it in the dumbest way: I delete the item, navigate to other screen, timeout 5ms and go back to the screen that I want to update.

```
function ListScreen({navigation}) {
<FlatList>
...stuff
<ListItem.Chevron onPress={ () => Alert.alert('Alert Title', 'Do you really want to delete this?',
 [{ text: 'YES', onPress: () => deleteAndRefresh(id) }
/>

 function deleteAndRefresh(id) {
        deleteProduct(id); //database call
        navigation.navigate('Home');
        setTimeout(function () {
            navigation.navigate('List');
        }, 5);   
 }
}
```

How could I refresh the screen inside deleteAndRefresh more ... elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try push ?

```
navigation.push('List');
```

Comment: cant because it is not a function, has to be () => navigation.push() and that did not work